Period of the modulus of a complex exponential sum
Consider a sum of exponentials function of the integer $x$: $f(x)=A(x)+B(x)$, where $A(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i  \theta_i^x$ with $\theta_i$ roots of unity, and  $B(x)=\sum_{j=1}^m d_j\lambda_j^x$   with $|\lambda_j|=1$ but not  roots of unity. Assume  the $\theta_i$'s and $\lambda_j$'s are all distinct, and that the coefficients $c_i,d_j$'s are all nonzero. It is known that $A(x)$ is a periodic function of period say $T_A$.
Now let us assume that $g(x):=|f(x)|$ is periodic of period $T_g$.
Question: what can be said about the relation between $T_g$ and $T_A$? In particular, is it true that $T_g\geq T_A$? Any reference would be appreciated.

Something here seems to be misstated. How is A(x) supposed to be periodic unless the $\theta_i$ are purely imaginary? Same question for $|f(x)|$.

@MichaelRenardy. Thanks, edited, sorry for the confusion.
